# Matlab Unknown class error after compiling script containing TCPIP

Tags: matlab, tcp, matlab-compiler

I compiled a script that uses the `tcpip` function from the instruments toolbox using MCR_R2015a. Running the generated executable on the PC I used for compiling (Windows7) is not a problem, however running it on another PC (Windows10, no Matlab installed) is. I receive the following error:

```
unknown variable com or unknown class com.mathworks.toolbox.instrument.TCPIP
```

pointing to line 123 in `tcpip`.  The surrounding code is:

```
try
    obj.jobject = handle(com.mathworks.toolbox.instrument.TCPIP(host,port));
catch aException
    newExc = MException('instrument:tcpip:cannotCreate',aException.message);
    throw(newExc);        %%% this is line 123
end
```

Obviously `com.mathworks.toolbox.instrument.TCPIP` is not known. I tried to find the file defining this object to append it when compiling without success.

Where to find that file or how to compile a running executable?

Comment: Update: After installing Matlab on the second PC (Win10), running the script in Matlab is not a problem. Then, I compiled another executable on the second PC, again using MCR_R2015a. Running the generated exe I receive the same error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was able to run the script inside Matlab but not the executable using the Matlab compiler runtime, I figured an unset path in the MCR may cause the error.

Not being able to find the file were the path to the TCPIP class is defined, I ended up deinstalling the MCR. Et voilá, it worked!

I am aware this solution is not answering the question how to compile scripts containing the `tcpip` function and running the generated exe on PCs that have no Matlab installed. But it is good enough for me.